# i get that error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

i wrote this query to get the employee who is manager to select minimum salary  for the employees who is managed by that manager

```
select min(e.sal) from emp e 
where e.mgr = (select empno from emp  where job = upper('manager'))
group by e.sal, e.mgr
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500

Comment: now i need to get managers and then get the lowest paid employee for that manager

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead!

Comment: Your query does not do what you think it does.  That is why you should provide sample data and desired results when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subselect `select empno from emp  where job = upper('manager')`  returns more than one row. 
You could change the WHERE-clause from `=` to `IN` - the result will be a list of all managers and the minimum salary of their employees:

```
select min(e.sal), e.mgr 
  from emp e 
where e.mgr IN (select empno from emp  where job = upper('manager'))
group by e.sal, e.mgr
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one manager in company, therefor this query you wrote returns more than one row:

```
select empno from emp  where job = upper('manager')
```

When you wrote the equal sign `=` you said to the SQL compiler that you're expecting only one row as a result, from the above query. Instead of writing the equal sign, you shoul use the `IN` function:

```
 e.mgr IN (select empno from emp  where job = upper('manager'))
```

The full code, as it should have been:

```
select min(e.sal) from emp e 
where e.mgr in (select empno from emp  where job = upper('manager'))
group by e.sal, e.mgr
```